# Make nil conform to a custom Protocol

Tags: swift

In order to practice Swift I have been working on a SQLite wrapper. Now it is time to add support for `NULL`. The current architecture of my wrapper looks like this:

I have a `func` that takes a query and an array of arguments. The arguments in the array have to confirm a protocol called `Bindable`. Every type which adopts this protocol knows how to bind instances of it to a SQL-statement. Thus it looks like this:

```
public protocol Bindable {
  func bindTo(statement:Statement, atIndex:Int32) -> Bool
}
```

I have made several types (`String`, `Int`) made to conform to this protocol. In order to support `NULL` I want to allow the argument array to contain `nil`-values like this:

```
let arguments:[Bindable] = ["Chris", nil]
```

This does not work.

In Objective-C I simply would add `-bindToStatement:atIndex:` to `NSNull` by using a category. Since `nil` is not a type in Swift I cannot extend `nil` and thus I cannot implement `Bindable`.

I could use `NSNull` but I would like to avoid that for the sake of doing it in Swift only. I could also create a constant called `SQLNullValue` that is an instance of a type that confirms to `Bindable`. But I would like to avoid that as well because I don't want to invent new things that represent `NULL`/the absence of a value.

So how would I do this in Swift?

Comment: How about `let arguments: [Bindable?] = ["Chris", nil]` ?

Comment: @ToddAgulnick is certainly right in one sense. You (the OP) won't be happy with whatever you do if you don't accept that `nil` is not only not a type but not even a value in Swift. It isn't really even a _thing_. It's just a literal notation, a shorthand for `Optional.None` - you can't use it unless there is an Optional in the picture.

Comment: This works but then I have a lot of special cases in my implementation where I have to check for nil and do something special instead of just calling a method on nil like I can with NSNull...

Comment: I said it before: It works and it is way better than a custom NULL value constant but not perfect IMHO...

Comment: @matt Yep, that was my Socractic suggestion -- you should embrace the optionals mechanism rather than trying to work around it.